# How to get n items sequentially in a Scala sequence

Tags: scala

Is there a way to get n items sequentially until the end in Scala? Like get (1..n), get (n+1..2n), get (2n+1..3n), ...

An example when `n` is `3`:

```
val items = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
items
  .myFunc(3)
  .map(subSeq => println(subSeq))
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8]
```

Comment: `items.grouped(3)`

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks @Tim

Comment: "That was easy" is the best bit about Scala :)